# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'theme.dart', 'colors.dart', 'ink_well.dart', etc

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, import, fft

Currently trying to run an example of a guitar tuner created with the 'flutter_fft' plugin, however, I'm receiving an error on some of my imports. I can see that all of these files exist inside my flutter folder but can't seem to access them?

**Here are my imports and the error I am receivingmy imports and the error I am receiving**
[image: my imports and the error I am receiving]

**But as you can see in this screenshot I do have all of those files available somewhere on my PC, and the material.dart import works fine?**
[image: import files are available]

I've been trying to work this out for a while but after asking a question here the other day and getting an almost immediate, and extremely helpful response, I've decided to come here again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: as much as i know, you need to provide full path. And those are already exported on `material.dart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When importing from a package (like flutter) you must first specify the package with a `package:` and then the path to the imports.

If you don't specify this, dart will assume you are trying to import a file on the same directory as the current file.

so instead of `import 'button_style.dart';` it should be `import package:flutter/src/material/button_style.dart`.

The above will work, but I will let you know that the sole purpose of importing `package:flutter/material.dart;` is to automatically import every file inside the `material` directory, and so, all of your imports are useless if you already import `material.dart`.